# I am trying to center a heading and then on the same line have a button on the right

Tags: html, css

```css
.heading {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline;
}

.button {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1 class="heading">Heading</h1>
  <button class="button">button</button>
</div>
```

Comment: why not use flex ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `float:right` to align button at the right position, and `text-align` in the parent div to make heading text at the center.

```css
.headBar {
  background-color: #828282;
  text-align: center;
}
.heading {
  display: inline;
}
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  float: right;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="headBar">
  <h1 class="heading">Heading</h1>
  <button class="button">button</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
div {
display: flex;
flex-flow: wrap row;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
width: 90vw; 
}

button { 
justify-self: flex-end;
}
```

** it’s possible the button needs “align-self: flex-end;” instead 
*** I assume this is just because it’s on stack overflow but try to give classnames that are different then the element name. If you must even btn is different-ish. 
**** this is off my phone so I haven’t tested the code but it should work

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by `text-align: center;` to `div` instead of `.heading` and `float: right;` to `.button` as follows:

```css
div{
     text-align: center;
}
.heading { 
     display: inline;
}
.button {
     display: inline-block;
     background-color: black;
     color: white;
     float: right;
}
```

```html
<div>
     <h1 class="heading">Heading</h1>
     <button class="button">button</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use float right to align the button in same line as that of Heading.And  for aligning the button to center you must include text-align:center in the enclosing div rather than in the heading class. The below code solves your issue.

```css
.new{
  text-align: center;
}

.heading {
  
  display: inline;
}

.button {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  float:right;
}
```

```html
    <div class="new">
        <h1 class="heading">Heading</h1>
        <button class="button">button</button>
    <div>
```